# random number between 1000 & 2000 for time of day

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

I'm looking to generate a random number between 1000 & 2000 for the time of day,  it has to be in 100 increments.  It's so I can test prebid timeouts and see different viewability figures and cpm's.  Then once I get enough data, I can work out the best settings for any given time of day and hopefully get better results.

help would be much appreciated.

This is what i have so far but i'm changing them by hand depending on the time of day I see peaks and troughs in traffic at the moment:

```
var timeoutMap = {
0 : 2000,
1 : 2000,
2 : 2000,
3 : 1600,
4 : 1600,
5 : 1600,
6 : 1400,
7 : 1400,
8 : 1400,
9 : 1400,
10 : 1400,
11 : 1400,
12 : 1600,
13 : 1600,
14 : 1600,
15 : 1600,
16 : 1600,
17 : 1600,
18 : 1600,
19 : 1600,
20 : 1600,
21 : 1600,
22 : 1600,
23 : 2000
};
var t = new Date().getUTCHours();
PREBID_TIMEOUT = timeoutMap[t];
console.log("prebid timeout:", PREBID_TIMEOUT );
```

Comment: Use `Math.random()` - or if that isn't enough `Math.floor(Math.random()*11)*100+1000`

Comment: or to make it general `Math.floor(Math.random() * n) * s + m` - where `n` is 11, the number of expected values, `s` is 100, the "step" size between values, and `m` is 1000, the minimum value expected

Comment: so this then?  Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) * 100 + 1000    do i literally put the following?:    var timeoutMap = {
0 : Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) * 100 + 1000,
1 : Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) * 100 + 1000,
2 : Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) * 100 + 1000,
3 : Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) * 100 + 1000,

Comment: i got it working, thanks alot

Comment: One assumption that you have here is that everyone has the same time of day and clock settings :-) I’d remove that or have that time dynamically created from your server time instead

Answer (score 1):

The general formula would be `minValue + randomFloatBetweenZeroAndOne * (maxValue - minValue)`. Then to get the steps of 100 it would be `randomNumGeneratedInPreviousStep / 100, rounded to nearest int, then multiplied by 100`.

```js
function generateRandom() {
  const randomNum = 1000 + Math.random() * 1000;
  return Math.round(randomNum / 100) * 100;
}
```

EDIT:

To make it more generic and allow you to customize aspects of this:

```js
function generateRandom(min, max, step) {
  const randomNum = min + Math.random() * (max - min);
  return Math.round(randomNum / step) * step;
}
```

If you wanted to apply this to your object for each value in your object, I would not make it super generic unless you knew you wanted to use it elsewhere. If that were the case, I'd wrap the general function in a more specialized function that closed on your specified values for this specifc use-case and do something like this:

```js
const MIN_RANDOM = 1000;
const MAX_RANDOM = 2000;
const RANDOM_STEP = 100;

function generateRandom(min, max, step) {
  const randomNum = min + Math.random() * (max - min);
  return Math.round(randomNum / step) * step;
}

function myRandom() {
  return generateRandom(MIN_RANDOM, MAX_RANDOM, RANDOM_STEP);
}

var timeoutMap = {
  0 : myRandom(),
  1 : myRandom(),
  2 : myRandom(),
  3 : myRandom(),
  ...
};
```

Comment: how do i work that into what i have above (p.s, i aint very good at this javascipt stuff) and does that limit to 2000 top end?

Comment: See edit above for application to your code. Let me know if any of it doesn't make sense and I'll clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.floor(Math.random()Into(max-min +1)) + min
```

By using this formula you can generate any range of value